# How to assign on-the-fly one-one communication using some basic rules

Tags: algorithm, logic, pseudocode

**Requirements**:

- You can have X number of people

  - These X people will be a set number before everyone is invited to log-in, set by an admin.
- Each person will be talked to the same number of times.

  - This will be configured by an admin.
- Each person can only talk to another person once
- A person can't talk to themselves
- A person will come in and get assigned upon log-in who they will communicate with (its not pre-determined)

**For example:**

- We have 6 people
- We can set a number of one way interactions between 1 and 5.

---

- **Possible 1**: Lets say we go with 6 one way interactions

  - Each person will talk to all the other people once. So Person A will talk to B, C, D, E and F

---

- **Possible 2**: Lets say we go with 2 one way interactions

  - Possible Combination 1

    - Person A will talk to: B and C
    - Person B will talk to: C and D
    - Person C will talk to: D and E
    - Person D will talk to: E and F
    - Person E will talk to: F and A
    - Person F will talk to: A and B
  - Possible Combination 2

    - Person A will talk to: D and F
    - Person B will talk to: C and E
    - Person C will talk to: F and A
    - Person D will talk to: B and C
    - Person E will talk to: A and B
    - Person F will talk to: D and E

---

Here is what I've come up with so far and I'll explain where I'm stuck.

- As User A I go in and request who I can communicate with.
- It will run through the following steps.

  - Goes out and finds any person I've already been assigned to communicate with.
  - Now gets a collection of all people, excludes the calling user and the people it already has been assigned to.
  - Now loops through those people and figures out how many users are talking to each of those eligible people
  - Now it will remove any of those eligible people who have been talked to by the maximum amount of interactions.
  - Finally will pick a random person from that list and assign them to me.

The problem is, lets say using from my example combo 1:

- User A got BC
- User B got CA
- User C got AB
- User D got CE
- User E only has F as an option but needs another person
- User F only has E as an option but needs another person
- F and E still are requiring another person to talk to them.

**What can I do to prevent my problem?**

Comment: Check out the solution to the Queen's Eight problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the "assigned upon login" criterion (unl;ess I am misunderstanding it). For example, when the first person (A) logs in there is nobody else for them to be 'assigned' to. Or, in a situation where each person is to be talked to once and you have 3 people (A,B,C) already logged in then

```
 A->B 
 B->C
 C->A
```

is a solution. But if D now logs in at a later time there is nobody for them to talk to so D's requirements cannot be met.

If, on the other hand, the admin can wait until all people are logged in then a simple solution for p people (labelled 1,2,3...p) each requiring communications with q <= p others is:

```
 for i = 1 to p
   for j = 1 to q
     i communicates with (i+j) mod p
```

If you want a different set of communications each time people log in, then just randomly assign the labels 1..p to the people A,B,...

Comment: Thanks! The second part I think will work. I added to my requirement that all the people will be pre-defined before users are invited to log-in. So I think I will pre-assign a random number 1-X (number of people) and use your formula to do the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When a person comes in and needs to be assigned which (other) people to talk to, slightly modify your procedure as follows:

1. get the list of all people, but leave yourself out, of course (because you can't talk to yourself).
2. ORDER that list based on how many times each one has been talked to.
3. fill you talk-to subset by picking from that ordered list "lowest first". This will improve the likelyhood that any next person coming in will have sufficient options.
4. as a possible further refinement, among the candidates with the same "low" count of talked-to stats, select first those who themselves have been talking less, if the whole set-up makes it more likely that THEY will be next coming in (so you would rather talk to them, leaving more OTHER people open for THEM).